# hp procurve trunk port group operation vs active lacp port group

Tags: best-practices, hp-procurve, trunk, ieee-802.1ax

We recently purchased some HP Procurve 2920 switches and in setting them up I noticed multiple options for port groups. I wanted to see if anyone can clarify functional differences between setting up a port group as a 'Trunk' vs an active LACP group. Can't seem to find definitive documentation on the function of the 'Trunk' option or what protocols it uses.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch has a built-in help function: `?`

```
xa-eng(config)# trunk 1-2 trk17 
 trunk                 Do not use any protocol to create or maintain the trunk.
 lacp                  Use IEEE 802.1ad Link Aggregation protocol.
 <cr>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not had a chance to get into the CLI for the HP switches that much and did not think to look there.  Looks like the 'trunk' option is a static bond whereas the LACP is an active group.  Thanks again!

Comment: And, yes, their help text does call it *802.**1**ad*

Comment: I noticed that... obviously a typo or someone's quick edit in the help file.  Thanks again for the quick response.  Looks like I'll be using the LACP since it's an actively negotiated connection.

Comment: @RickyBeam Wow, that should be brought up to their production team.

Comment: @Fizzle I just checked our switches with the same command and it now shows IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Protocol.  I think someone caught that as these switches were shipped this month. :-D